# Should Page Objects be reused or should new ones be created?

Tags: java, pom

I am fairly new to using POM and I am wondering if there is a best practice when returning to a previously visited page. Is it better to create a new page object every time there is a page navigation? Or is it ok to reuse variables where the page is already instantiated?

Example of Page object reuse:
Since loginpage is already defined I just use it again

```
public void LoginTwice()
{
    LoginPage loginpage= new LoginPage();
    loginpage.GoTo();
    loginpage.login("user","pass");
    WelcomePage wlcmPage= new WelcomePage();
    wlcmPage.Logout();
    
    //login again
    login.GoTo();
    loginpage.login("user","pass");
    wlcmPage.clickMenu();
}
```

Example of new page object creation: loginpage is set to a new instance of LoginPage

```
public void LoginTwice()
{
    LoginPage loginpage= new LoginPage();
    loginpage.GoTo();
    loginpage.login("user","pass");
    WelcomePage wlcmPage= new WelcomePage();
    wlcmPage.Logout();
    
    //login again
    loginpage= new LoginPage();
    login.GoTo();
    loginpage.login("user","pass");
    wlcmPage= new WelcomePage();
    wlcmPage.clickMenu();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 there is a best practice when
```

["There are good practices in context, but there are no best practices."](https://context-driven-testing.com/)

When you first create the *LoginPage* object, it has the context of the first landing on the page. It may have loaded internal information relevant to this first landing (which the tests don't need to know).

When you perform login and logout and then use the same object from before, its internal state may not match the current state of the application (which is different from the first landing).

One approach you can do is to delegate to the page objects the responsibility of understanding under which state the page object should be, using [Method Chaining](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/method-chaining-in-java-with-examples/).

Your tests could something like this:

```
LoginPage loginpage = new LoginPage();
loginpage.visit()
         .login("user","pass")
         .logout()
         .login("user","pass")
         .clickMenu();
```

When you perform *visit*, the method will return a *LoginPage* object, *login* will return a *WelcomePage* object, *logout* will return a *LoginPage* object, so on and so forth...

Whatever details these objects will need to have can be configured by the methods you are calling in your tests. These methods should know the full context of what happens when you perform some action, not your tests. The tests should care only about the user flow.

Comment: Ok so each of these methods would return a new object every time?

Comment: Yes. Typically, if the action doesn't change the page, the method would "return this;" - otherwise, it would create the proper page object representing the page the action led to and "return new FollowingPage();"

Comment: Ok thank you for your input. One other quick question related to pages... what if the action doesn't always change the page? Or what if the action has the possibility of returning two different pages depending on the scenario? Would you just create a method that returns each possible page?

Comment: "doesn't always change the page" => "return this;"  || "two different pages depending on the scenario" => I can imagine you refer to a possible second tab or windowed page. In this case, you can return a data structure that contains references to the two page-objects and let the client decide how to drive the user flow.